# How to calculate the percent of numbers below a certain number?

Tags: r

There are several built-in R data sets on the 50 United States. For instance, `state.area` shows the area of each U.S. state, and `state.abb` shows a common abbreviation. To access the datasets, you may just type the dataset names in R console.

Find the percent of states with area less than New Jersey (NJ).

What percent have area less than New York (NY)?

I basically need to figure out how to find the percent of numbers below a certain number?

Answer (score 0):

```
mean(state.area < state.area[which(state.abb == 'NJ')])
[1] 0.08

mean(state.area < state.area[which(state.abb == 'NY')])
[1] 0.4
```

Comment: This is what my professor said ti was: which(state.area<7836) 

[1]  7  8 11 39 

4/50*100 

[1] 8

Comment: My answer is equivalent. Your professor's answer just multiplies the result by 100 for presentation. `0.08 * 100 = 8`. Their version also manually specifies the area of NJ, while mine gets it by searching the `state.abb` vector. But to each their own, I guess.